# Debug error in NetBeans

Tags: c, netbeans, debugging

I am running a C program in NetBeans (cygwin on windows). Generally for all C programs I have run in the past, while debugging, it stops and shows the line number of segmentation fault. But for this particular program, it does not show the line number and just stops and in the output tab, it shows prog stopped by SIGSEGV. I have tried conditional breakpoint, but it is not stopping. What could be the other conditions for error?

If u want have a look at my program, here it is.http://codepad.org/cujYTIeg

and the in.txt file from where it reads the input. http://codepad.org/vNySA6uh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you run the program in debug mode with debugging information enabled?

Try to set a normal breakpoint in your Appliocation. Does it stop there?

Comment: Ya it is running in debugging mode. 
No it does not stop there after a normal breakpoint. I think the problem is since my functions are making recursive calls, so may be stack is overflowing. I m not sure.

Comment: it also may be that your debug info files are corrupted. you could try delete all temporary/intermediate files from your project and do a complete rebuild.